# magento 2 get multi valued attribute field values of product

Tags: magento2, php

I want `Dealer store view` attribute value of product.

I have tried this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

$optionsExists = array();

foreach($options as $option) {

    $optionsExists[] = $option['value'];
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($optionsExists); die;
```

[image]

Comment: When you want this? What is the name and attribute code of that attribute? Can you also update what you have tried?

Comment: You need to Dealer Store View means 10,20,30 etc but according to your code its returns only the value id not label.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'geslacht');
$attribute->setStoreId(1); // Add your store view ID of Dealer Store View. In my case its 1.
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

$optionsExists = array();

foreach($options as $option) {

    $optionsExists[] = $option['label'];
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($optionsExists);
?>
```

Hope this helps!